# Save the Errors in Database instead of errors.log in cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, error-handling, cakephp-1.3

I need to save errors which occur in my application into a database table, rather than writing out to `errors.log`. I'm using CakePHP, and a little lost as to how to achieve this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1582/Creating-and-configuring-log-streams